# Duplicate Path symbols

Tags: java, path, nio

Please can someone help me interpret what is means when either `\\..\\..` or `\\.\\.` is in a **Path**. I understand that `\\.` is the working directory and `\\..` is the parent of the working directory but I can't conceptialise what it means when they are duplicated.

```
    Path path = Paths.get("aa\\cc\\..\\..\\b.txt").normalize();
    System.out.println(path);
```

output is *b.txt*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

".." in a file path is the parent of the working directory as you said so ".." followed by ".." just means go to the parent of the parent.

The path you provided: `"aa\\cc\\..\\..\\b.txt"` is identical to just `"b.txt"`. The path `"aa\\cc\\..\\..\\b.txt"` says starting at the working directory to go down to directory `aa` then down to `cc` then back up to `aa` then back up to the working directory and then find file `b.txt`.

Answer (score 1):

Every directory in the filesystem has some special built-in files that are always present in them. On Windows filesystems this includes `.`, `..`, `NUL`, and `CON`. The `.` path element is a special built-in directory entry which refers to the directory itself. Similarly, the `..` entry is another special built-in directory entry which refers to the parent directory of its location. The "working directory", on the other hand, is maintained by the shell and automatically used as a path root for any relative paths provided to it.

So `.` only appears to be the "working directory" since specifying it will be relative to the working directory maintained by the shell -- in the same way that "readme.txt" is the readme.txt file in the working directory. The '.' can appear anywhere in a path to (unnecessarily) reference the directory at that location. And the `..` can appear to reference the parent directory "1 up" from its location.

So, for example:

```
/home/jdoe/.
```

refers to the directory `/home/jdoe`. Similarly `..` is the parent of the directory. So:

```
/home/jdoe/..
```

refers to the parent of `jdoe` which is `/home`.

You can sometimes chain these together to your heart's content so all of the following path statements refer to the exact same directory (that being /home/jdoe):

```
/home/jdoe
/home/jdoe/.
/home/jdoe/././././.
/home/jdoe/../jdoe
/home/jdoe/subdir/..
```

The Java Paths `normalize` function removes all the '.' and '..' parts and modifies the path accordingly to simplify the path without changing the actual end location of it.

Note that '..' can allow you to create invalid paths that try to run above the root directory. Such as `/home/jdoe/../../..`.